# Optimizing mysql query which contain more then 20 inline tables

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am using MySQL database. Request you to please suggest Some Good practice for query building. I have already applied indexing for Join on clause columns.

Below query is taking 13 sec for execution. Is there any alter way to reduce execution time up to 2 or 3 sec?

Thanks.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  pd.id AS pid,pd.request_number,pd.requester, pd.desc_of_auto,
               pd.benefits,pd.frequency_task, pd.freq_days,pd.time_spent_cur_hr,
               pd.time_mgr_hr, pd.time_belowmgr_hr,pd.remarks,pd.expected_save_dollar_yr,
                pd.expected_save_dollar_desc, ROUND(pd.total_time_save_hr) AS total_time_save_hr,
                pd.total_cost_save, DATE_FORMAT(pd.exp_start_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS exp_start_date,
                pd.reasons_challenges_to_start,pd.approx_effort_hr,pd.approx_cost_dollar,
                DATE_FORMAT(pd.req_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS req_date, pd.gtmt_hr,
                DATE_FORMAT(pd.expected_end_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS expected_end_date,
                pd.time_mgr_hr_mst,pd.time_belowmgr_hr_mst,pd.gtmt_hr_mst,
                pd.conversation_rate,pd.higherValues, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dm.dept_name)
                    FROM  dept_mst dm
                    LEFT JOIN  dept_payback_mst dpm  ON dpm.DeptId = dm.id
                      AND  dpm.Status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = dpm.PaybackId
              ) AS dept, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dm.id)
                    FROM  dept_mst dm
                    LEFT JOIN  dept_payback_mst dpm  ON dpm.DeptId = dm.id
                      AND  dpm.Status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = dpm.PaybackId
              ) AS deptid, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sm.Sbu_name)
                    FROM  sbu_mst sm
                    LEFT JOIN  sbu_payback_mst spm  ON spm.SbuId = sm.Sbu_id
                      AND  spm.Status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = spm.PaybackId
                      AND  sm.Sbu_id IN (1000)
              ) AS sbu, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sm.Sbu_id)
                    FROM  sbu_mst sm
                    LEFT JOIN  sbu_payback_mst spm  ON spm.SbuId = sm.Sbu_id
                      AND  spm.Status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = spm.PaybackId
                      AND  sm.Sbu_id IN (1000)
              ) AS sbuid, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cm.Cmp_name)
                    FROM  cmp_mst cm
                    LEFT JOIN  comp_payback_mst cpm  ON cpm.CompId = cm.cmp_id
                      AND  cpm.Status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = cpm.PaybackId
              ) AS comp, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cm.cmp_id)
                    FROM  cmp_mst cm
                    LEFT JOIN  comp_payback_mst cpm  ON cpm.CompId = cm.cmp_id
                      AND  cpm.Status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = cpm.PaybackId 
              ) AS compid, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT rm.Resource_Name)
                    FROM  resource_mst rm
                    LEFT JOIN  resource_payback_mapping rpm  ON rpm.resourceId = rm.id
                    WHERE  pid = rpm.PaybackId 
              ) AS resreq, 
              ( SELECT  um.UserName
                    FROM  user_mst um
                    WHERE  um.id = pd.requester 
              ) AS reqName, 
              ( SELECT  prm.priority
                    FROM  priority_master prm
                    WHERE  prm.id = pd.req_priority 
              ) AS reqPriority, 
              ( SELECT  stm.req_status
                    FROM  status_master stm
                    WHERE  stm.id = pd.req_status
                      AND  stm.req_status = '4- Completed' 
              ) AS reqStatus, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT um1.UserName)
                    FROM  user_mst um1
                    LEFT JOIN  proj_champ_paymst pcp  ON pcp.champ_id = um1.id
                      AND  pcp.status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = pcp.PaybackId 
              ) AS proj_champ, 
              ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT um2.UserName)
                    FROM  user_mst um2
                    LEFT JOIN  proj_team_member_paymst ptm  ON ptm.team_member_id = um2.id
                      AND  ptm.status = 'Active'
                    WHERE  pid = ptm.PaybackId 
              ) AS proj_team, 
              ( SELECT  tym.type
                    FROM  type_master tym
                    WHERE  tym.id = pd.dataUpload 
              ) AS type, 
              ( SELECT  fmm.freqName
                    FROM  freq_mst fmm
                    WHERE  fmm.id = pd.frequency_task 
              ) AS frqName
            FROM  project_detail pd
            WHERE  (pd.total_time_save_hr > 0
                      OR  pd.expected_save_dollar_yr > 0
                   )
              AND  IFNULL(YEAR(expected_end_date), YEAR(NOW())) IN (2015 ,
                        2016
                         )
            GROUP BY  pd.request_number , pd.id
            ORDER BY  DATE(expected_end_date)
      ) u
    WHERE  reqStatus = '4- Completed'
      AND  sbuid IN (1000)
      AND  compid IN (1000 , 1003,1100,1101,1200,1600, 2001, 2002,
                2003,2004,2005,2006,4000,4100,4200,4300 
                     )
```

Comment: Questions about query optimisation always require, as a minimum, CREATE table statements for each of the relevant tables, as well as the EXPLAIN for that query. In this instance, I'd be tempted to try to reduce the query to just the parts that are crippling performance

Comment: Thanks Strawberry! Moving to my second question, Is there any way to reduce execution time for above query?

Comment: See previous comment

Comment: Is there a bug?  You seem to be computing `compid` as `GROUP_CONCAT`, then testing it via `IN(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should reformulate the query.

`sbu_mst JOIN sbu_payback_mst WHERE ...` shows up twice.  If, instead of subqueries like that, you used a `JOIN`, it would not need to be evaluated twice.

Ditto for `cmp_mst`.

Without much more rearranging (and `JOINing`) you can probably get rid of the outer query.

Don't use `LEFT` when the `WHERE` handles the situation.  Example: `LEFT JOIN  sbu_payback_mst spm ... pid = spm.PaybackId`

*Some* indexes that might be needed:

```
dept_payback_mst: (PaybackId, Status, DeptId)
       -- unless it already has PRIMARY KEY(PaybackId)
proj_team_member_paymst: (PaybackId)
```

Comment: Perfect! I have replace current indexing with your suggestion and it's work perfectly. And also kept all where in inner query as having.